Como posso ajustar para o objetivo que é Como adicionar usuários (vértices) e suas relações de amizade (arestas) ao grafo?
Estou escrevendo um codigo em PYTHON e pretendo adicionar usuario e relacionar entre eles em um ciclo de amizade e também Como posso ajustar para o objetivo que é Como adicionar usuários (vértices) e suas relações de amizade (arestas) ao grafo?
Segue o codigo para ajuda ok.
def exibir_menu():
    print('''Escolha uma opção:

    1. Cadastrar Usuario
    2. Listar pessoas cadastradas
    3. Procurar dados de uma pessoa
    ''')
def cadastrar(usuario):
    identificador = input('Id? ')
    nome = input('Nome? ')
    redesocial = (input('redesocial? '))
    usuario.append((identificador, nome, redesocial))
def listar(usuario):
    for usuario in usuario:
        identificador, nome, redesocial = usuario
        print(f'Nome: {nome}, redesocial: {redesocial}, id: {identificador}')


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá foram fornecidas orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).

Não duplique as publicações https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/594862/137387 . Faça edições na publicação original esclarecendo de maneira objetiva qua o real problema. Se o problema é apensar dados em um grafo, o ideal é apresentar um [mcve] mostrando como faz a modelagem do grafo e as rotinas de adição de vertices e arestas que estão dando problema, assim como dados de depuração e logs de erro
